# Fairly Complex List Select Problem

Tags: gui-design, lists, hyperlinks, tags

Im wondering if you guys can add some expertise...

I have the following problem, and I would like to know if anyone here has any ideas or solutions.

Essentially, the user will create a post, and the user then needs to place that post into different categories (x amount of potential categories), but each category has X amount of linked categories.

So when the user adds a category, they also need the ability to potentially select one or all of the link categories to add to the delivery of the post.

What would you guys suggest to be a good experience for this?

Comment: Welcome to UX Stack Exchange. Can you please show us what you've tried so far, posting screen shots if possible? Then, tell us what you think isn't working about the designs.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

I think you may find inspiration in the way products like *deviantart* do tag selection:
[image: Screenshot of deviantart tag input, showing an input field with suggestions]

As you can see, you have a free text field, where user can input several tags. While you write, tags (or in your case categories) can be selected. **You can extend this by showing the user proposed sub-categories after they entered a category in the suggestions dropdown**. This may be an elegant solution.

First however, think long and hard whether you actually do need this feature in this manner. Exposing internal data structure to the user is usually a bad idea, and may hint at a suboptimal interface metaphor.

Whatever you do, try to avoid forcing users to understand or memorize your category structure. Unless it is expert software and the categories solve some massive pain for your users in an obvious way, they'll hate it.